# converting RGB and HSV values in matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors, octave

I created an animation to see the different values of RGB and the equivalent HSV values using `rgb2hsv` but the `colors don't match at all` am I using the conversion incorrectly?  *I was expecting to get similar colors and get the equivalent HSV values to that of the RGB values*, How can I do this?

Example code I used to test along with animation below.

[image: rgb2hsv values]

```
clear all,clf reset,tic,clc
pkg load image
for ii=1:5:255
  ii;

  r(:,:,1)=127;
  g(:,:,1)=mod(19+ii,255);
  b(:,:,1)=12;
  rgb_img(:,:,1)=r;
  rgb_img(:,:,2)=g;
  rgb_img(:,:,3)=b;
  rgb_img=uint8(rgb_img); %convert so Imshow an show image

  hsv_img=rgb2hsv(rgb_img);
  h=hsv_img(:,:,1);
  s=hsv_img(:,:,2);
  v=hsv_img(:,:,3);
  hsv_img=uint8(hsv_img); %convert so Imshow an show image

  pause(.0001)

  height_wanted=300;%size(img,1) %length wanted needs to stay size(repmat_rgb,1) to get all colors. only change for testing
  width_wanted=280; %width wanted can be changed

  rgb_out = imresize(rgb_img, [height_wanted, width_wanted]); %reshape output
  hsv_out = imresize(hsv_img, [height_wanted, width_wanted]); %reshape output

  str_rgb1=('RGB Values');
  str_rgb2=(sprintf('\nRed=%3d  Green=%3d  Blue=%3d',r,g,b));
  str_hsv1=('HSV Values');
  str_hsv2=(sprintf('\nHue=%0.3f  Satuation=%0.3f  Value=%0.3f',h,s,v));

  subplot(1,2,1);imshow(rgb_out); title([str_rgb1,str_rgb2]);
  subplot(1,2,2);imshow(hsv_out); title([str_hsv1,str_hsv2]);
end
```

Ps:  I'm using Octave 4.0 which is like Matlab

Comment: Showing the actual `HSV` values as an image doesn't make any sense.  You are converting colour pixels in RGB space to a non-linear colour space where each component: Hue, Saturation and Value cannot directly be mapped to physical RGB colours that you would see **unless** you convert back to RGB.  That's why what you're seeing is nonsense. Let me ask you another question. What is the intended purpose of what you're doing here?

Comment: `rgb2hsv` returns double values in the range `[0,1]`. Converting that to `uint8` does not automatically scale; you'll have to do that manually.

Comment: And, as @ray said, the colors won't match :)

Comment: @rayryeng I was trying to obtain the different RGB and HSV values that would produce the same / similar color.

Comment: @RickT Unfortunately, when MATLAB displays an `m x n x 3` matrix, it displays it as an RGB image. So even though you know that the first channel is Hue, it'll be displayed as the Red channel. That's probably not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, you can't display an HSV image just like any other image because it is a fundamentally different color representation. A 3-D HSV image matrix will not display as anything particularly meaningful with image display functions in MATLAB (like [`imshow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imshow.html)) because they will simply interpret them (wrongly) as an RGB image (i.e. hue channel is treated as red, saturation channel is treated as green, and value channel is treated as blue).

What you probably want to do instead is display each HSV channel separately:

- The hue as an index into an [HSV color map](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hsv.html).
- The saturation as a grayscale representation of the amount of color present (0 = grayscale, 1 = pure color).
- The value as a grayscale representation of brightness (0 = darkest, 1 = lightest).

Here's some code that will make a figure similar to yours, but with 4 plots instead of 2 (I believe this should work in both MATLAB and Octave):

```
rgb_img = zeros([300 300 3], 'uint8');
redValue = 127;
rgb_img(:, :, 1) = redValue;
blueValue = 12;
rgb_img(:, :, 3) = blueValue;
hsvMap = hsv(360);
figure('Position', [100 100 1000 500]);

for greenValue = 0:5:255
  rgb_img(:, :, 2) = greenValue;
  hsv_img = rgb2hsv(rgb_img);
  hsvIndex = round(hsv_img(:, :, 1).*359)+1;
  h_img = reshape(hsvMap(hsvIndex(:), :), [300 300 3]);

  subplot(1, 4, 1);
  imshow(rgb_img);
  title(sprintf('RGB = (%3d, %3d, %3d)', redValue, greenValue, blueValue));
  set(gca, 'Visible', 'on', 'Box', 'on', 'XTick', [], 'YTick', []);

  subplot(1, 4, 2);
  imshow(h_img);
  title(sprintf('Hue = %0.3f', hsv_img(1, 1, 1)));
  set(gca, 'Visible', 'on', 'Box', 'on', 'XTick', [], 'YTick', []);

  subplot(1, 4, 3);
  imshow(hsv_img(:, :, 2), []);
  title(sprintf('Saturation = %0.3f', hsv_img(1, 1, 2)));
  set(gca, 'Visible', 'on', 'Box', 'on', 'XTick', [], 'YTick', []);

  subplot(1, 4, 4);
  imshow(hsv_img(:, :, 3), []);
  title(sprintf('Value = %0.3f', hsv_img(1, 1, 3)));
  set(gca, 'Visible', 'on', 'Box', 'on', 'XTick', [], 'YTick', []);
  drawnow;
end
```

And here's the animation:

[image]